# How can I integrate Zoom in a reactjs app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, zoom-sdk

How can I integrate zoom with reactjs app?

We have a ReactJS frontend and Node.js backend application running. I need to integrate Zoom API to my application.

Please share the steps to integrate the same.

Comment: Here is the working example https://github.com/shkhalid/zoom-web-sdk-react-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Support Links - - -**

https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-web
https://github.com/zoom/zoomus-jssdk

**Install Process -- - -**

npm install zoomus-jssdk

https://zoom.github.io/sample-app-web/tutorial-get-start.es6-integration.html

Comment: Updated Zoom Web SDK NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoomus/websdk

Updated Zoom Web SDK Docs: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web

Answer (score 2):

Zoom has now launched a fully customisable SDK as well which is **Video SDK**.

Official Doc: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/introduction

Differences between Video SDK & Client/Web SDK: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/compare

Video SDK Sample app: https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-videosdk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a zoom meeting programmatically in your application, you have to first register your app with Zoom and then you will get API Key and Secret Key. These two keys will be used in your API code to interact with Zoom API to create, update or to perform other zoom meeting operation. You can find the steps and code written in Node JS in below blogs:

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting.html

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting_18.html